# .first() vs. .one() in craft 3

Tags: templating, elementcriteriamodel, elementquery, twigextension

I'm confused about the new `.one()` argument in craft 3

If I want to grab all entries I write:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('thing').all() %}
  {{ entry.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

Alls is nice and well. 20 something entries are returned.

But I want to fetch only the latest entry so instead of `.all()` I use `.one()` (which was formerly `.first()`)

But when I write:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('thing').one() %}
  {{ entry.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

It returns the error:

> Impossible to access an attribute ("title") on a string variable
>   ("3").

When I write:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('portfolioEntry').limit(1).all() %}
  {{ entry.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

Then it works. But that's not the right way, is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.all()` returns a collection of elements, which you can loop through with a for loop.

`.one()` returns a single element, so you cannot use a for loop to access it.

In this case you should just store the entry like:

`{% set entry = craft.entries.section('thing').one() %}` and then access `{{ entry.title }}` afterwards.

(Also keep in mind that entry is automatically populated for section URLs, so you may want to use another variable name)